# Is it possible to trigger a workflow without editing the record

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, automation

I have a custom date/time field where the result is calculated depending on other fields so the result will be dynamic. I created a workflow which will fire if the custom date/time field  = NOW().

My question is, will the workflow run even if I did not edit the record? I have tried it many times but the workflow only works when the record is edited and saved manually.

If the workflow wont work this way, what workarounds can I do to achieve this requirement?

Thanks

Comment: do you want workflow to be triggered based on custom date/time field changes?

Comment: How you are currently updating this custom date/time field?

Comment: Workflow rules are triggered only when the record is updated. The criteria is checked before taking workflow actions. But before criteria check workflow must be triggered by record update.

Comment: @santanuBoral the custom date/field is updated via Trigger. I want to trigger the workflow when the custom date/field = NOW() without manually edit/save the record.  How can I trigger a workflow without record update

Comment: Is that Erik's answer solves your issue?

Comment: @santanuBoral unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a task for a time based workflow

Note: It will trigger at the specified time but may not run until 15 minutes later

1. Create a time based workflow

   - Criteria Edited and subsequently meets criteria
   - Find a field that will cause it to initially execute
   - Set the time based on the date/time field for 0 hours from the value

When the initial criteria from the second bullet is met (Say isClosed = true) is met the WFR sets to fire 0 hours from the Date/Time field.

The neat part is, if the date/time field changes dues to an edit, that alone will cause the WFR to reschedule to the new value of the Date.Time field.

You can test this by creating a TBWFR with criteria of when the Opp is Closed. Have the time trigger based off of a date time. Review the Queue and see it is there. Now, change the date/time field and even though the criteria did not change you will see the queue is updated to reflect the new time.

Aside from that, a batch process would be in order

Comment: Hi @Eric, It will work if the record will be edited, however, it must be automated to escalate at custom date/time field value

Comment: No it does not, I believe you misunderstand how TBWFR act. If the record is created / update to meet the criteria and the date / time is set then the WFR will fire at that time in the date time field. The only time this would not work is if your date time is not set.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this without using batch job?

Comment: Yea, with the time base WFR. As I said, it works unless the date/time field is blank. What type of field is your date/time field and how is it set?

Comment: I used formula field. I followed this tutorial https://sftipshack.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/the-5-minute-time-based-workflow-or-15-minute-or-30-minute/

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that if you do it right that link's instructions do indeed work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43791/discussion-between-gelay-and-eric).

Comment: and it will be recurring even if i dont edit the record??

Comment: Have the Time based WFR do an trivially edit on the record which will alter the date which should cause the war to be reschedule again

Comment: You mean the time triggered action in workflow right? After the workflow update the record, the time triggered action will no longer work unless i manually edit and save the record.

Comment: Well, if you have as part of the time trigger action a field update of some sort the date time field will change and thus the WFR will be rescheduled. If you read my answer you would know this. How do I know, well we send an email on a due date. After it is sent we change the due date and the WFR is rescheduled even though the due date in not part of the criteria. Have you even tried it?